# Marshal Structure SizeOf error

Tags: vb.net, structure, marshalling

I have a load of UDTs, I'm trying to use Marshal and FileGet to read a record into a Structure.

The function is fine with the first structure which only contains a Long and an Integer, the structure is returned, no problem.

My problem starts with the second record.

I have the structure defined with the MarshalAs properties for each field:

```
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
Public Structure typStaticData
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AsAny, SizeConst:=8)> Public DateStamp As Nullable(Of Date)       '8
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U8)> Public Farmcode As Nullable(Of Long)        '8
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AsAny, SizeConst:=8)> Public StartDate As Nullable(Of Date)       '8
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U8)> Public NoTrans As Nullable(Of Long)         '8
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Public ClosingVisit As Nullable(Of Boolean) '1
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)> Public FileType As Nullable(Of Byte)        '1
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr)> Public Cat As String
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AsAny, SizeConst:=8)> <VBFixedArray(11)> Public VisitDates() As Nullable(Of Date)      ' (1 To 12)    ' 12 * 8
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> <VBFixedArray(11)> Public VisitDOC() As Nullable(Of Boolean)     ' (1 To 12)    ' 12 * 1
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr)> Public filler As String
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Currency, SizeConst:=16)> Public fillercur As Nullable(Of Decimal)    '16
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U8)> Public fillerLong As Nullable(Of Long)      '8
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AsAny, SizeConst:=8)> Public ERRDate As Nullable(Of Date)         '8
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AsAny, SizeConst:=8)> Public fillerDate1 As Nullable(Of Date)     '8
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AsAny, SizeConst:=8)> Public fillerDate2 As Nullable(Of Date)     '8
End Structure
```

The Subroutine to Read the data is:

```
   Public Sub ReadBinaryFile(ByRef outValue As Object,
                          Optional ByRef inRecordCount As Integer = 1)
    Const C_PROC_NAME = "ReadBinaryFile"
    ' remember to convert Dates from their "Long/ticks" equivalent

    If iFreeFile = 0 Then Exit Sub

    Try
        Dim recordLength As Integer = Marshal.SizeOf(outValue) '<-------------
        Dim myBytes As Byte() : ReDim myBytes(recordLength)

        FileGet(iFreeFile, myBytes, inRecordCount)
        BuildStr(myBytes, outValue.GetType, outValue)
        inRecordCount += 1
    Catch ex As Exception
        If gDebug Then Console.WriteLine(CODE_MODULE & "-" & C_PROC_NAME & ": " & ex.Message)
        oERR.LogFileError(inModule:=CODE_MODULE,
                          inRoutine:=C_PROC_NAME,
                          inEX:=ex, inErr:=Err)
        If gDebug Then Stop
    End Try
End Sub
```

The error I keep getting, and can't get past is:

```
ReadBinaryFile: Type 'Claims32.modStaticData+typStaticData[]' cannot be marshaled as an unmanaged structure; no meaningful size or offset can be computed.
```

I've tried several different

Where am I going wrong here, and what else do I need to do?

Comment: You cannot use MarshalType.AsAny.  The odds that the file actually contains any Nullable are zero.

Comment: What do I do the Date as? A U8 (Long)? or something?

Comment: A Double, probably.  And convert with DateTime.FromOADate().  But that's just wildly guessing when you don't document anything about the code that wrote the file.  We try not to guess here, it isn't useful to anybody.

Comment: The code that wrote the file was VB6 ~~~ Open file for binary as #1 : Put #1,, UDT ~~~ that is why I have no idea as to lengths of the undefined strings. The values that are defined as Date are stored as Date. I'm trying to read those files in VB.NET and the closest that has to ~~~ Get #1,, UDT ~~~ is FileGet() but I need to get the length of the Structure to REDIM the Bytes array.